# Given an Odd Function, Which of the following must be necessarily be equal to $f'(-x_o)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was answering some questions for incoming quizzes when a wild question appears. It looks like this:

> Suppose that $f$ is an odd function for all $x$. Suppose that $f'(x_o)$ exists. Which of the following must be necessarily be equal to $f'(-x_o)$?
>
> A. $f'(x_o)$
>
> B. $\frac{1}{f'(x_o)}$
>
> C. $-f'(x_o)$
>
> D. $-\frac{1}{f'(x_o)}$

**My work**

I think that the answer would be **C**. Why? The funtion I know that fits in the description of the equation above would be the cosine function $y = \cos x$.

Differentiating $y = \cos(x)$, it becomes $y' = - \sin(x)$. Then everybody knows the property of sine function: $\sin (-x) = -\sin(x)$.

So....

$y' = -\sin(x)$ is just equal to $y' = \sin(-x)$. So if the problem states that "**Which of the following must be necessarily be equal to $f'(-x_o)$?**" , then, I think.....$f'(-x_o)$ would be equal to $-f'(x_o)$ (which is the choice **C**). It works on cosine function......

Is my logic correct?

Because it seems that the function being described could be anything other than cosine function...but I don't know what are other functions 
that could fit on the problem statement other than the cosine function.

Comment: $\cos(x)$ is not an odd function. For a test case, try $\sin(x)$. Or even simpler, try $x$.

Comment: @quasi damn..why didn't I realized it soonerXD

Answer (score 2):

No, it's incorrect. Your approach has two flaws. First of all $\cos$ is an **even** function. Second you should not draw conclusions from only one example.

To find the solution what you use is the definition of an odd function, that is $f(x) = -f(-x)$. Then you can for example use the chain rule:

$$f'(x) = {d\over dx} -f(-x) = -f'(-x)\cdot (-1) = f'(-x)$$

which means alternative (a). If you can't use the chain rule you can use the definition of the derivate directly:

$$f'(-x) = \lim {f(-x+h)-f(-x)\over h} = \lim {f(x) - f(x-h)\over h} \\=\lim{f(x)-f(x+h)\over -h} = \lim{f(x+h)-f(x)\over h} = f'(x)$$

Comment: What about someone's suggestion that  using a test case, like trying  sin(x). Or even simpler, try x? Is it valid? It seems that I need a couple of equations that could answer the question above.....

Comment: @PalautotKa Not really. At best it could be used to pinpoint the alternative, but some test cases might fulfil other answers as well. In the end that one odd function fulfils the alternative A does not necessarily mean that all odd function does - for showing that you need a more generic argument.

Answer (score 1):

Show that

$\frac{f(-x_0+h)-f(-x_0)}{h}=\frac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{-h}$.

This shows that the answer is $A$.

Answer (score 0):

A geometric approach is also possible. The derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ is the slope of the tangent $\ell$ to the graph of $f$ at $(x_0, \: f(x_0))$. Now $f$ is odd means its graph is symmetric about the origin, thus the tangent $\ell'$ at $(-x_0, \: f(-x_0))$ is the reflection of $\ell$ about the origin. Since point reflection maps lines into parallel lines, $\ell$ and $\ell'$ share the same slope, which means that the derivative at $x_0$ equals that at $-x_0$.